# Error ( JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)) when using capiq-python package

Tags: python, r

I am trying to use the `capiq-python` package to pull data from S&P Capital's website (Documentation -  https://github.com/faaez/capiq-python). I'm inexperienced in Python, so I'm using `reticulate` in R to do this.

It appears that I've managed to install the package successfully with the following code. I also installed the `requests_cache` module as I was getting an error without it.

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("git+git://github.com/faaez/capiq-python.git", pip = TRUE)

py_install('requests_cache')
requests_cache <- import('requests_cache')
```

Next, I've tried to run the following lines of code in a script (using the `py_run_file` function) as in the documentation (to initialize the wrapper with my username and password, before creating a dataframe)

```
from capiq.capiq_client import CapIQClient
ciq_client = CapIQClient("username", "password")
return_value = ciq_client.gdsg(["TRIP"], ["IQ_CLOSEPRICE"], ["close_price"], properties=[{}])
```

However, it gives me the following error

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is this an error with the actual package? Or something that can be fixed? Hoping to find a solution from someone that has access to S&P Capital IQ

TIA!